# Android 4.0 features with examples

Tags: android, sample, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want to implement Android 4.0 features in my app.
If any one has sample code could you please share?

I mainly need examples for photo editing (taking some part according to our finger touch points).

Answer (score 13):

Using the Android SDK manager you can download the package "Samples for API14" which contains a lot of example Apps for Android 4.0 alias Ice Cream Sandwich / API14.

After installing this package you will find the sample apps in the folder `samples\android-14` within your android sdk directory.

Those demo Apps cover a large number of new features introduced with Android 4.

Comment: @shok: Acknowledgments on Stackoverflow are nice - nicer would be if you would accept my answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.